# Pasting the last cell of a group_by in a new column in R perhaps using loops or mutate

Tags: r

```
data %>%
group_by(ID, Interest, Event) %>%
mutate(??)
```

I want my "Final Interest" column to look like below. Basically, the last cell of "Interest" column from the group_by condition.

| ID | Interest | Event | Final Interest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | A1 | 1 | T1 |
| 1001 | A1 | 1 | T1 |
| 1001 | D | 1 | T1 |
| 1001 | T1 | 1 | T1 |
| 1001 | T1 | 1 | T1 |
| 1001 | T1 | 1 | T1 |
| 1002 | A7 | 7 | T7 |
| 1002 | D | 7 | T7 |
| 1002 | T7 | 7 | T7 |
| 1002 | T7 | 7 | T7 |
| 1002 | T7 | 7 | T7 |
| 1002 | T7 | 7 | T7 |

Comment: `mutate("Final Interest" = last(Interest))`

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID, Event) %>% mutate(Final_Interest = last(Interest))`?